# Committed project deleted by Visual studio solution is there any problem?

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I have solution in VS2013. Our project changes once we committed it updated to Cloud forge.

In that i have a 3 sharepoint projects in One Solution.Now i want to delete one project.If i delete the project and i will commit is there any problem..?